# granting Cloud CDN access to your buckets?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-cdn

im trying to use Cloud CDN with backend bucket but it keeps telling me that i should "grant Cloud CDN access to your buckets by adding the Cloud CDN service account to your access control list".
I tried modifying the bucket permissions so that "AllUsers" IAM had every permission, but the CloudCDN still kept telling me to "grant Cloud CDN access to your buckets"

So how do you add the Cloud CDN service account to your access control list?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1):

The only IAM permission required for a file to be usable by the CDN is to have the "allUsers" IAM user with "Reader" access permissions. This can be easily accomplished by simply making sure that the file is [Shared Publicly](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/cloud-console#_sharingdata). What you see in the Cloud Console UI is a warning rather than an error. If this is not affecting your service, just ignore this warning.

Comment: A public issue has been filed. You can keep track of it here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/110202126